# Problems that involve time intervals and their overlapping

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I have recently came across a lot of questions that involve time intervals as an input. Some of the time intervals are overlapping. And depending upon that you have to perform an optimization, maximization or minimization operation on the input. I am not able to solve such problems. In fact, I am not able to even start thinking on these problems.

Here is an example:

1. Let us say, you are a resource holder. There can be an infinite supply of such a resource.
2. There are people who want that resource for a particular time interval. For ex: 4 pm to 8 pm
3. There can be an overlapping interval. ex: 5 pm to 7 pm, 3 pm to 6 pm
   etc.

Depending upon these intervals, and their overlapping nature, you have to figure out how many distinct instances of these resources are required.

Ex. Input:

```
     8 am - 9 am
     8:30 am to 9:15 am
     9.30 am to 1040 am

     In this case, the first two intervals overlap. So two instances of resources will be required. The third interval is not overlapping, so the person with that interval can reuse the resource returned by any of the earlier ones.
```

Hence, in this case, minimum resources required are 2.

I don't need a solution. I need some pointers on how to solve. Are there any algorithms that address such questions? What should I read/ study. Are there any data structures that might help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The data structure you need to use in order to solve this type of problems is [The Interval Graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_graph). The Interval Graph has a vertex for every interval and an edge between every pair of vertices corresponding to intervals that intersect.

The following interval graph corresponds to the set of three intervals in your example:

[image: interval graph]

```
A: 8:00-9:00
B: 8:30-9:15
C: 9:30-10:40
```

This data structure captures the relevant aspects of most problems involving intervals and thus helps to solve them efficiently. Also, given the set of intervals (represented by a list of 2-tuples), you can construct the interval graph in Polynomial time.

Many problems that are NP-hard in general graphs, such as finding the [Maximum Weight Independent Set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_set_(graph_theory)#Maximum_independent_sets_and_maximum_cliques) or finding the [Optimal Coloring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_coloring), can be efficiently solved for interval graphs.

To solve the particular problem you've specified, first construct the interval graph `G`, while storing for each vertex the finish time of its corresponding interval. Also initialize a set of resources `R={1}` that at first contains only a single resource: resource number 1. Consider each vertex `v` of `G` in sorted order according to their finish time. Assign to `v` resource number `i`  where `i` is the smallest resource in `R` not used by the neighbors of `v`. If no such a resource exists (because the neighbors of `v` use all the resources in `R`), insert a new resource `i=max{R}+1` to `R` and assign it to `v`. The optimal number of resources (aka, the solution to your problem) is the size of the set `R`.

Comment: This is a nice answer. Never heard of interval graphs earlier. Can you suggest a resource(other that wikipedia page) to learn this Data structure more? It would be helpful

Comment: @neerajdorle, a series of short video lectures by Georgia Tech does a good job at explaining the topic: https://pwp.gatech.edu/math3012openresources/lecture-videos/lecture-10/ . They even use a variation of the problem you've encountered to demonstrate the concept.

Answer (score 9):

The number of intervals overlapping any time instant T is the number of interval start times less than T, minus the number of interval end times less than or equal to T.
Many of these problems, like the specific one above, can be solved by putting the start and end times separately into a sorted list or tree so you can figure out stuff about how these counts change over time.

To solve this problem, for example, sort the start and end times in a single list:

```
800S, 900E, 830S, 915E, 930S, 1040E
```

then sort them:

```
800S, 830S, 900E, 915E, 930S, 1040E
```

The run through the list and count, adding 1 for each start time and subtracting one for each end time:

```
     1     2     1     0      1     0
```

The highest number of overlapping intervals is 2.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Simple and easy!

Comment: perfect answer, thanks for posting a simple solution