# Algorithm for geometry problem involving orthogonal lines cutting through a rectangle

Tags: algorithm, geometry

I am stuck at this programming problem for a while and don't really know how to do it.

We are given a big rectangle, and a series of smaller non-overlapping rectangles within the big rectangle.

How do you devise an algorithm to find the maximum number of partitions the big rectangle can be partitioned into using orthogonal lines given that 1) every partition has to have at least one smaller rectangle and 2) whenever a line is drawn, the number of partitions must increase by at least 1.

Comment: I assume you mean that every partition needs to have *at least* one rectangle in it?

Comment: Yup that's what I mean. Oops I didn't realise it's confusing. I edited the question to make it clearer. And actually for the partitions it's also that it must increase by at least one also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rule (2) means that your cutting lines never cross -- each one cuts an existing partition into 2 pieces.

Rule (1) means that you are really just trying to find the number of groups that you can divide your small rectangles into using horizontal or vertical cuts.  Quite often, the answer will be the same as the number of small rectangles, but sometimes you cannot divide them all.  For example, a group of rectangles arranged this way cannot be cut without dividing at least one of them in two:

```
   AAAAAAAA  BBB
   AAAAAAAA  BBB
             BBB
   CCC       BBB
   CCC       BBB
   CCC
   CCC  DDDDDDDD
   CCC  DDDDDDDD
```

To make as many groups as possible, you can follow a simple recursive procedure:

1. Make as many vertical cuts as possible
2. In each resulting partition, make as many horizontal cuts as possible
3. In each resulting partition, go back to (1) until you can not make any new cuts

To determine the maximum number of cuts you can make in a partition, you just consider the end coordinate of every rectangle in the other direction (if you're cutting vertically, for example, then look at every rectangles max X).  If a line through that coordinate doesn't cross any other rectangles, then cut there.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it works. But is there a faster way to do this perhaps in O(n^2 log n) time where n is the number of small rectangles because I have a time complexity constraint. Because I think for this if at every recursion step only 1 cut is made then this would take a lot of recursions?I was thinking of doing like divide and conquer and trying to split the big rectangle into 2 before recursing but I don't know how to take into account cases when you can't cut at all. And thanks for this

Comment: This procedure takes O(N^2) time in the worst case, as long as you do all the sorting at the start -- put the rectangles into 4 lists, one each sorted by min x, max x, min y, max y.    Then partition all lists with every cut, maintaining the orders in each partition.  Each scan+cut operation takes O(N)  time, using the two list method for finding overlapping intervals: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48401761/problems-that-involve-time-intervals-and-their-overlapping/48402852#48402852